# How do I change Eclipse from Java IDE to C++ IDE?

Tags: java, c++, eclipse

I am using a PC running Windows 8, and I have been coding in Eclipse prior to getting this laptop, but I cannot remember how to change the code to C++. Thanks!

Comment: http://eclipse.org/cdt/ ?

Comment: I'm baffled by your question. Can you try rewording it? I don't know if you're trying to move your project to the new laptop, install CDT in Eclipse, or switch to the C++ perspective.

Answer (score 3):

[image]After you've installed the [developer tools for c/c++](http://eclipse.org/cdt/) you can change between different perspectives in the toolbar in the upper right corner, or under the menu `Window/Open Perspective/Other`

Answer (score 0):

where you coding Java on Eclipse on the laptop? if that is the case then Java is a different programming language and cannot change the code to c++.

If you have the C++, you have to install Eclipse CDT on that new laptop.